# How to include userid, pass to WifiClient connect() api

Tags: wifi

These are my remote server credentials that I want to connect from my local device.

```
Server  m12.cloudserver.com
User    <myname>
Password    <mypassword>
Port    19999
_ or 
api_key 5678909876-009-00d
```

I want to use the WiFiClient client() API as shown, but where or how do I include the User credentials ? so that I can make a successful connection to the remote server from my device connected over Wifi.

Cut and paste from my Arduino code.

```
const int httpPort = 19999;
if (!client.connect("m12.cloudserver.com", httpPort)) {
 Serial.println("connection failed");
 return;
}
```

Comment: Read the API docs.

Answer (score 1):

WifiClient provides low level tcp connection. Your server seems to be implementing a REST API interface. Thus you need to construct HTTP headers (GET, POST, etc.) manually as a string. Then you can add your credentials. Before doing so, try to use your server, I mean call api's with the program named `Postman`. Postman runs on Chrome browser. `Postman` can compose such headers for you. Then you can insert them into your arduino code.